# PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = uuid

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, uuid

I have this repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DomainRepository extends CrudRepository<Domain, String> {
    Domain findByUuid(UUID uuid);
}
```

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="a", schema="b")
public class Domain {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private UUID uuid;

}
```

But when I do
`Domain d = domainRepository.findByUuid(UUID.randomUUID());`

I get `PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = uuid` (column type in table is `VARCHAR`).

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try defining the type for the field as Hibernate unable to understand the type by annotating field with `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")`

```
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType")
private UUID id;
```

Answer (score 2):

If specifying type didn't help you also can try smth like this:

```
public class UUIDConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData == null ? null : UUID.fromString(dbData);
    }
}
```

and modify you entity field:

```
@Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
private UUID id;
```

This solution adds type conversion every time you retrieve entity and also requires you to place `@Convert` annotation for each uuid field, but as workaround this will do.

Also make sure that column in database has varchar/text type, otherwise it may fail(if you don't want to or can't replace types from uuid to varchar, just create view)

Comment: `@Converter(autoApply = true)` helps avoiding field annotation.